executing a market buy order through Kucoin API
I have just started with the Kucoin API
but I'm having trouble executing a market buy order in the futures market using python.
I'm using this Github as a reference:
 https://github.com/Kucoin/kucoin-futures-python-sdk

heres the code I tried:
from kucoin_futures.client import Trade
client = Trade(key='myKey', secret='mySecret', passphrase='myPP')

client.create_market_order(symbol="ZEROUSDTM", side="buy",funds=1, lever=1)

however this returns the following error:
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\kucoin_futures\base_request\base_request.py", line 128, in check_response_data
raise Exception("{}-{}".format(response_data.status_code, response_data.text))
Exception: 200-{"msg":"Quantity parameter cannot be empty.","code":"100001"}

does anyone know where I'm going wrong?
Thanks for reading

by default orders are limit orders. So you need to specify price and size attributes. This is according the API manual:
https://www.kucoin.com/docs/rest/spot-trading/orders/place-order
